# Use angular translate with parameters and HTML

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, ng-bind-html

I have a translation label with parameters and html :

```
{
    "myLabel": "There is <b>{{param}}</b> value."
}
```

I don't arrive to pass my parameter and to get the HTML interpreted. I try many option :

### Option 1 : Use ng-bind-html with translate filter

```
<p ng-bind-html="{{'myLabel' | translate:{param: vm.myParam} }}"></p>
```

But I get this error :

```
angular.js:14642 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7B'general.help.notion.text3'%20%7C%20translate%3A%7BnbButton%3A%20vm.nbBtn%7D%20%7D%7D&p4=%7B'general.help.notion.text3'%20%7C%20translate%3A%7BnbButton%3A%20vm.nbBtn%7D%20%7D%7D
    at angular.js:88
    at r.throwError (angular.js:15200)
    at r.object (angular.js:15189)
    at r.primary (angular.js:15078)
    at r.unary (angular.js:15066)
    at r.multiplicative (angular.js:15053)
    at r.additive (angular.js:15044)
    at relational (angular.js:15035)
    at r.equality (angular.js:15026)
    at r.logicalAND (angular.js:15018) "<b ng-bind-html="{{'general.help.notion.text3' | translate:{nbButton: vm.nbBtn} }}">"
```

Is there a way to use `ng-bind-html` with a parameter ?

### Option 2 : Use translate directive

```
<p translate="myLabel" translate-values="{'param': vm.myParam}"> </p>
```

But what I get is for example : `There is <b>2</b> value.`

My current sanitize strategy for angular translate is `escaped`, I tried with `sanitize` but in french all my accent are converted into their html code, for example : *Déroulement d'un chapitre*
I also try the `escapeParameters` and `sanitizeParameters` strategies and always I get : `There is <b>2</b> value.`

Do you know how I can achieve that ?

Thanks in advance
Takeshi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<p ng-bind-html="'myLabel' | translate"></p>
```

Remember to include `$sce` service.

Comment: How is the `param` parameter provided in this way?

Comment: @lealceldeiro param is filled automaticly. If you have a translation with `{{expression}}` the expression is interpolated by default mechanism of Angular.

Comment: In fact without the `{{}}` it works. With my example : `<p ng-bind-html="'myLabel' | translate:{param: vm.myParam}"></p>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`$translate`](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate) service in order to get the string translated in the controller (providing the `param` as parameter), then set the translated value to a var and bind (`ng-bind-html`) this var in the view.

Something like this (*I did not use the `controllerAs` syntax for brevity*):

**controller js**

```
$scope.message = "About to be translated..."

  $translate('myLabel', {param: 1}).then(function (text) {
                $scope.message = $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
            }, function (textID) {
                $scope.message = $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
            });
```

**view**

```
<p ng-bind-html="message"></p>
```

<kbd>**[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fuvkhOv5VXqANJAstSKe?p=preview)**</kbd>

Remember to inject the `$sce` service.

Comment: Yes it works, but I'm not really fond of managing translation inside a controller. Thx

Comment: Yes, I use this option only as a last resource too. But it works, anyways :)